# Wireless Problem (broadcom)

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, broadcom

I can connect to my wireless, but I can't connect to the internet.

Things I've tried that didn't help:

- Getting closer to router
- Formatting
- Reinstalling firmware

Some diagnostic details:

- `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

  ```
  # Generated by NetworkManager
  nameserver 94.143.178.17
  nameserver 195.167.65.194
  ```
- `nm-tool`

  ```
   NetworkManager Tool

  `State: connected (global)

  - Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
    Type:              Wired
    Driver:            tg3
    State:             unavailable
    Default:           no
    HW Address:        00:1D:72:28:DF:B9

    Capabilities:
      Carrier Detect:  yes

    Wired Properties
      Carrier:         off


  - Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
    Type:              802.11 WiFi
    Driver:            b43
    State:             disconnected
    Default:           no
    HW Address:        00:1F:3A:56:5E:73

    Capabilities:

    Wireless Properties
      WEP Encryption:  yes
      WPA Encryption:  yes
      WPA2 Encryption: yes

    Wireless Access Points 
      EFESSOU GEUSEIS: Infra, 00:05:59:0B:6C:37, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength     54


  - Device: ttyUSB0  [Cosmote Default] -------------------------------------------
    Type:              Mobile Broadband (GSM)
    Driver:            option1
    State:             connected
    Default:           yes

    Capabilities:

    IPv4 Settings:
      Address:         31.152.209.75
      Prefix:          32 (255.255.255.255)
      Gateway:         10.64.64.64

      DNS:             94.143.178.17
      DNS:             195.167.65.194
  ```
- `sudo iwlist scan`

  ```
  lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

  eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

  irda0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

  wlan0     Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: 00:05:59:0B:6C:37
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
                Encryption key:off
                ESSID:"EFESSOU GEUSEIS"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                          36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000000333425f1b6
                Extra: Last beacon: 784ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000F45464553534F552047455553454953
                IE: Unknown: 010582848B962C
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C

  wwan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

  ppp0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
  ```
- `cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`

  ```
  [main]
  NetworkingEnabled=true
  WirelessEnabled=true
  WWANEnabled=true
  WimaxEnabled=true
  ```
- `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

  ```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback
  ```
- `lsmod | grep b43`

  ```
  b43                   318816  0 
  mac80211              272785  1 b43
  cfg80211              172392  2 b43,mac80211
  ssb                    50682  1 b43
  ```
- `route -n`

  ```
  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  0.0.0.0         10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
  10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
  169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ppp0
  ```

I ran those codes when I was online with my broadband connection. If you need any command to be executed when I am connected with my wireless (which has problems) please tell me.

Comment: can you also post the output of the following command?  route -n

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots ok i did

Answer (score 0):

The output of iwlist and lsmod you included show that your computer recognised and can use the wireless card, so it's not likely a driver issue.

Based on your routing table, it looks like your computer is set up to send all internet traffic through the ppp0 interface and not the wlan0 interface.  try unplugging/disabling any modems or VPNs that you have configured, then try connecting to wireless again.

Answer (score -1):

Your wired properties carrier (whichever it is) is off. You must activate it.

```
echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control
```